# Changing munin hdd plugin used UUID

Tags: disk, munin

I've backed up my ubuntu server, and changed the HDD. Now I need to know where is the old UUID saved on the system? It seems that munin will no longer work with the HDD plugins, I guess it's looking for the old HDD UUID.

I have change the UUID for /boot in fstab, so it boots up properly, but where do I change more?

blkid output looks like this

```
[13:49:28]slaffe@scenics:~$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="26970b8a-f72a-40b3-a7fa-346bb06ce34e" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sda5: UUID="V2ksPy-37U3-EAd0-NQs5-BcLX-FHeZ-fIVL2I" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/scenics--vg-root: UUID="55c1a2a2-536b-4f42-ac9d-4c0f672c8f95" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/scenics--vg-swap_1: UUID="7af82ae7-f30b-4832-a15b-4b90efe47312" TYPE="swap"
[13:49:29]slaffe@scenics:~$
```

This is my *new* hdd, so where in the system is the old uuid saved?

Hope you guys can help me out here.